# Sketch: как перетащить группу элементов?

Tags: дизайн, design

Sketch: как перетащить группу элементов с активным параметром click-throught when selecting. 
[image]

Сверху группа с отключенным параметром, внизу с включенным.
https://gyazo.com/935fa2f5f402f51cfe33f5971ccba392
Щелкаю по элементу, нажимаю ESC чтобы поднятся на уровень выше в слоях, тем самым выделяю папку, которую нужно переместить, но при клике мыши снова проваливаюсь во внутрь, вместо желаемого перемещения. Может есть хоткей, который позволяет перемещать выделенный в данный момент слой\группу, а не делать выбор?